# JS switch based on selected option

Tags: javascript, html

I try to write simple JS switch which will display content based on selection, so lets say i will have html doc with 4 div's if user will select option one div one will  be displayed etc.

Here is fast draft which i made but it don't work. Can you please help me understand what i'm doing wrong here ?

HTML

```
  <legend>Selecting elements</legend>
          <p>
             <label>Select list</label>
             <select id = "myList">
               <option value = "1">one</option>
               <option value = "2">two</option>
               <option value = "3">three</option>
               <option value = "4">four</option>
             </select>
          </p>
       </fieldset>
       <p id ="demo"></p>
```

JS

```
function myfunction () {
        var text;
        var city = getElementById("myList").value;

        switch(city) {
            case "one":
            text ="test one";
            break;

            case "two":
            text ="test two";
            break;

            case "three":
            text ="test three";
            break;

            case "four":
            text = "test four";
            break;

            default:
            text = " ";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
            }
```

Comment: who is calling `myfunction()`

Comment: So what's happening now? Can you quote the question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with the code

```js
function myfunction() {
  var text;
  var city = document.getElementById("myList").value; //need to use document.getElementById()

  switch (city) {
    //the select values are 1, 2, 3 not one, two etc
    case "1":
      text = "test one";
      break;

    case "2":
      text = "test two";
      break;

    case "3":
      text = "test three";
      break;

    case "4":
      text = "test four";
      break;

    default:
      text = " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<legend>Selecting elements</legend>
<p>
  <label>Select list</label>
  <!--Need to call myfunction on change of the select-->
  <select id="myList" onchange="myfunction()">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
  </select>
</p>
</fieldset>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

---

If you just want to show a predefined text then

```js
var mymap = {
  1: "test one",
  2: 'test two',
  3: 'test three',
  4: 'test four'
}

function myfunction() {
  var city = document.getElementById("myList").value; //need to use document.getElementById()
  var text = mymap[city] || ' ';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<legend>Selecting elements</legend>
<p>
  <label>Select list</label>
  <!--Need to call myfunction on change of the select-->
  <select id="myList" onchange="myfunction()">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
  </select>
</p>
</fieldset>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Ah now i get it ! Thank you :) That worked. Nope i want to display specific div with content and hide another - which i will support by jquerry but that was just draft to test it i know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

onchange="myfunction()"

add this for call your function